# Majorara zero mode in Ising chain, not exactly zero subtlety

Tags: condensed-matter, ising-model, majorana-fermions

We know the transverse field Ising model with N sites(open boundary), can be mapped into N free fermions(there are 2N modes if including the negative energy counterparts)  With property:
$$\gamma^\dagger(\epsilon)=\gamma(-\epsilon)$$
As long as $\epsilon \neq 0$, our $\gamma^\dagger(\epsilon)$ is still a regular fermion operator, with property:  $\gamma^2=0$

In the $h<1$ ferromagnetic phase, the lowest fermion mode energy can be exponentially small $\epsilon \sim h^N \sim e^{-cN}$

Then people say since $\lim_{N \rightarrow\infty }\epsilon=0$ , we have $\gamma^\dagger(0)=\gamma(0)$ a Majorana mode!

What I'm confusing is when $\epsilon \neq 0$, we have $\gamma^2=0, \{\gamma,\gamma^\dagger\}=1$ , which should also hold in the limit. The anti-commutator can not get a sudden change.

$$\lim_{N \rightarrow\infty }\gamma^2=0 \qquad \lim_{N \rightarrow\infty }\{\gamma,\gamma^\dagger\}=1 $$
Which is still regular fermion, contradict with the Majorara mode property $\gamma^2=1$

So why do we call it Majorara zero mode, not a fermion near-zero mode?
$$\lim_{N \rightarrow\infty }=\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+} \neq \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow0 }$$

Or perhaps $\gamma^\dagger(0)=\gamma(0)$ is just the linear combination of $\gamma(0^+)$ and $\gamma(0^-)$

Comment: I think you are confusing the fermionic modes with the majorana modes. Note that the majorana modes are always there, and it is just an alternative way of writing your system. In particular, there are N fermionic modes, or equivalently 2N majorana modes. Since in your first sentence you say there are 2N fermionic modes, I suspect you are confusing them with each other. The notation $\gamma$ is usually also preserved for majorana modes. Can you be more precise about what you mean by '$\gamma^\dagger(\epsilon)$?

Comment: The $\gamma^\dagger $ is means Jordan-Wigner fermion. $H=\sum_i  \epsilon_i ( \gamma^\dagger_i \gamma_i -  \gamma_i  \gamma^\dagger_i )    \qquad \qquad  $  The $\gamma^\dagger(\epsilon)$ means the same as $\gamma^\dagger_i$ with energy $\epsilon=\epsilon_i  \qquad \qquad $

Comment: Ah okay, in that case your Hamiltonian is the same as $H = \sum 2 \epsilon_i \gamma^\dagger_i \gamma_i$ (up to an irrelevant constant). If the lowest energy is $\epsilon_0$, then we indeed find that $\epsilon_0 \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$. This means that $\gamma_0^\dagger$ is the fermionic mode that relates the (nearly) degenerate ground states $|0\rangle$ and $\gamma_0^\dagger |0\rangle$. In this description the majorana modes are not made explicit. But it turns out that you can decompose $\gamma_0 = c + i \tilde c$ where $c$ and $\tilde c$ are majorana modes. [continued]

Comment: [cont.] Note that such a decomposition of a (Dirac) fermion into majorana 'fermions'/modes can *always* be done. What is special in this case is that it turns out that $c$ is localized on the left edge, and $\tilde c$ on the right edge. Hence we can say that there are Majorana modes living on the edges of the Kitaev chain. These two Majorana modes together make up a 'non-local' fermionic mode that can be filled or empty, characterizing the twofold ground state degeneracy.

Comment: [Note: these majorana modes only live on the edge of the chain in the fermionic representation, not in the original spin system. So it is invalid to say that the Ising chain exhibits majorana modes. However, the above reasoning does for example apply to a 1D p-wave superconductor (which is what Kitaev was working with) and so that system does have majorana modes living on its edges.]

Comment: The degeneracy is 2 in the language of $|0>$ and $\gamma_0^\dagger |0>$, now we have two Majorana modes $c$ and $\widetilde{c}$, the degeneracy looks like 4, is their any constraint on the two Majorana modes? They have to be there both. Or both empty?

Comment: Majorana modes are a bit weird in that sense: you can't occupy them like normal fermionic operators, since $c = c^\dagger$. In other words for fermions we have $\gamma^\dagger \gamma$ which is $0$ or $1$ and denotes the twofold degeneracy. However for Majorana modes we have $c^\dagger c = c^2 = 1$. You need two Majorana modes to have a well-defined twofold degeneracy, counted by $i \tilde c c$. (This becomes natural if you plug in the relationship $c = \gamma + \gamma^\dagger$ and $\tilde c = \frac{\gamma - \gamma^\dagger}{i}$. Try it out.)